# React JS & HTML : Calculating the height of the container by the given objects from API (inside the container)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So basically what I'm trying to do is to set the container height to a specific number. So let me explain. I have an API that is returning Reports and the React JS renders them in this window (video [Gyazo - MP4](https://i.gyazo.com/ebcfbd5a611552322efd6a6c7d255326.mp4))

As you can see the page renders the height correctly for a maximum of 6 objects, If there are more than 6 I need to increase the container height. So basically I'm using styled-components, so I can pass in the value there to set the height.

**My question is how to calculate it correctly?**

Here's my styled-component CSS:

```
export const ReportContainer = styled.div`
  height: 1100px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #010606;

  @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    height: 2600px;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 563px) {
    height: 2630px;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 410px) {
    height: 2630px;
  }

`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made it by giving it an auto height and setting the minimum height to 900px;

```
height: auto;
min-height: 900px;
margin-top: 100px;
```